# Does dart doc support generation of markdown instead of HTML?

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dartdoc

I have `dart doc .` working and generating HTML files.

I want to generate Markdown files instead.

When googling, I found this answer https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/1479#issuecomment-868961953 - which led me to this PR: https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/pull/2703

In the diff https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/pull/2703/files - I see `format` and `md` - but I'm new to this, so I don't know how to use this info to create the command I need to use.

I was expecting something like `dart doc . --format md` to work, but it doesn't.

Also, when I run `dart doc --help`, it leads me here: https://dart.dev/go/dartdoc-options-file - and it doesn't mention the ability to generate docs in Markdown.

Maybe this isn't supported? TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dart doc` can't create documentation in markdown format, you have to use the package `dartdoc` (see https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/3241#issuecomment-1302150336)

You have to run `dart pub global run dartdoc --format=md` (but the generated `md` may not be pure `md`, see https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/3237).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation and clarification! I appreciate your time and expertise.